# Launch image for iPhone would not show up with Xcode 5 in landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode5

When starting a project using Xcode 5, I can't seem to get the launch image for iPhone to show up in landscape mode.  I have tried both using Asset Catalogs and not using Asset Catalogs.

For testing, if I start a project using Xcode 4.x, then it works fine.  It also works fine if I opened a Xcode 4.x project using Xcode 5.

Any suggestions?

[image: Not using Asset Catalog]

[image: using Asset Catalog]

[image: Using Asset Catalog: icons files]

[image: Using Asset Catalog: Launch images files]

Comment: It seemed like this is a bug.  Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110583/iphone-landscape-only-no-launch-image-for-ios7-r4-image-asset

Answer (score 0):

You must select the [Use Asset Catalog] button and select which asset catalog corresponds to your app icon and launch image.

Your project file should look like this when that is completed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly a bug for iOS7(and previous)/Xcode, Apple just does not want apps to start in landscape mode with a launch image.

See http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10316 for more details on why.

One possible fix is to manually name each image according to convention, that supposedly fixes it.  Another may be to have a launch file instead, although I haven't personally tried that.  Good luck.