# iOS 7 iPhone Launch Image is black for landscape-only app

Tags: ios7, xcode5, launchimage

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007750/2880799), but now do I have to actually support portrait?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the image, clean the project then relaunch xCode.
If it still not working, open the organizer and delete the temporary data.

Answer (score 0):

> Avoid using asset catalogs to manage the launch images of landscape
>   applications. Except for launch images used by the iPhone 6 Plus,
>   asset catalogs assume that all iPhone launch images are for the
>   portrait orientation. When your application is compiled, entries for
>   each launch image are added to the compiled information property list
>   under the UILaunchImages key. The value for the
>   UILaunchImageOrientation key in each of these entries is always
>   Portrait. These entries are then ignored at launch time because the
>   value of Portrait for the UILaunchImageOrientation key does not match
>   the launch orientation (Landscape Left or Landscape Right). The result
>   is a blank screen during launch as the system cannot find an
>   appropriate launch image.

Source https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2244/_index.html