# Splashscreen won't show on landscape application (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, uiinterfaceorientation

In my landscape application I can't manage to show splash screen on iPhone. I know I can't show directly a landscape image, in fact I rotated it in my image editor. 
But when I try to launch the app, only a black screen is showed before the first view.
Everything works fine for iPad. How can I solve?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Here I found the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110583/iphone-landscape-only-no-launch-image-for-ios7-r4-image-asset