# iPhone5 Default image with Assets Catalog not working

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit

Already added iphone5 Default-568h@2x.png image, but it is displaying black screen on launch and displays black strip inside game.

Here is Screenshot

[image]

Anything else I need to specify for iOS7 to read Default-568h@2x.png image ?

Comment: Try to clean -> build.

Comment: not worked..when I turn off use assets catalog then works...why not working with assets catalog? what's my wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Asset catalog has a bug with launch images in landscape format. See also:

[iPhone landscape-only no launch image for iOS7 R4 image asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110583/iphone-landscape-only-no-launch-image-for-ios7-r4-image-asset/22106849#22106849)