# AssetCatalog LaunchImage Landscape only - iPhone 4S/5/5S not shown

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

For a Sprite Kit Game i am providing my LaunchImages through an AssetCatalog.

The catalog looks like this:

[image: LaunchImage AssetCatalog]

The image is shown correctly on:

- all iPads
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6 Plus

The image is not shown on:

- iPhone 4S
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 5S

I am developing for a minimum target `iOS 8`

Can you figure out what is going wrong? As you can see i even added the portraits for the iPhone to see if anything is loaded as launchimage - but nada..

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19110583/2274694

Comment: @LyndseyScott sadly doesnt help too much :/ still stuck.. when i deselect the iOS 7/8 the phone will open in cropped mode (showing 3.5 inch plus bkack frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by going the old proven way:

[image]

- Provide all the above assets for apps in landscape only
- Dont use AssetCatalog

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to select the iOS8.0 and later box for iPhone Portrait?

Comment: this will only add iphone 6 & 6 Plus portrait assets - which are already correctly shown

Comment: Is the "Launch Screen from .xib" option disabled?

Comment: The only thing that still comes to mind is delete and reload the iOS7,8 iPhone portrait landscape images, or even put some different test ones there to see...

Comment: i did it the old fashined way through naming conventions without the asset catalog ;) thank you for your hel though!